# How to Approach Linear Machine-Learning Model When Input Variables are Inconsistent

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, dimensionality-reduction, python-3.x

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to the data science and ML world -- still trying to get a firm grasp on the fundamentals.

I'm trying to overcome a regression challenge involving a large, multi-dimensional dataset, but am hitting a roadblock when it comes to my input data.

This dataset consists of a few key input criteria: [FLOW, TEMP, PRESSURE, VOLTAGE_A] and a single output variable, VOLTAGE_B (this is what I'm hoping to effectively model and predict). I'm able to handle this data easily enough when I force the input values to be consistent, but my approach starts to breakdown and lose fidelity when I utilize the *actual* experimental data.

For ex: In an ideal setting, each subset of input data will have some samples at [0.0, 10.0, and 20.0] degC. In reality though, I have data subsets where one may be [0.1, 9.9, 19.8] degC and another will be [0.2, 10.1, 20.1] degC. I'm not totally sure how to handle this inconsistency in my input data. In my model I am discretizing the data by coercing the input values to the nearest digit, but this is certainly causing losses with the fidelity of my model.

For context: presently I'm using a the sklearn Linear Regression toolkit, via Python.

**MAIN QUESTION**

- Is there a good (recommended) and method [that doesn't require a $20k/ year subscription] for training a linear regression model when the inputs are all unique, and non-repeating?

Comment: not sure what your question means. the whole concept of modeling is that your input data DOES vary.  if it was the same all the time, there would be nothing to model. Can you clarify?

Comment: agree with @RalphWinters. Generally, reason why we train a model is to predict what the output would be given different inputs. If a change of 0.1 in `TEMP` has an impact, it should be captured by the trained model. I do not see what the question is.

Comment: And to question: *"Is there a good (recommended) and method [that doesn't require a $20k/ year subscription] for training a linear regression model when the inputs are all unique, and non-repeating?"* I have even less clue what it means (especially the *"unique non-repeating"* phrase). But there are numerous free open source frameworks readily available, and SkLearn is one of them.

Comment: Thanks all, after some additional research I think I understand the source of my confusion. I've found a solution by implementing SKlearn